# Highlight cursorcolumn covers any existing highlights

Tags: vim

I'm trying to enable Cursorcolumn/row in my vimrc but the column covers existing highlights for some reason (see image below).

[image: cursorcolumn covers existing highlights]

I moved `set hlsearch` and `"syntax on` after the hgihlight cursorcolumn commands but that didn't help.

As the image above shows, this is only a problem for the cursorcolumn though -- it works as expected for cursorline (highlighting is fine).

Any idea on how I can fix that? Here's my vimrc

```
set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set nu
set expandtab
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set wrap
set foldmethod=syntax
set foldlevel=20

set tags=/data/mabdelfa/build_two/p4/acl/llvm/tags

"show trailing whitespace
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()

"highlight current row/column
" TODO figure out todos
:hi CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=236 guibg=236
:hi CursorColumn cterm=NONE ctermbg=236 guibg=236
:nnoremap <Leader>c :set cursorline! cursorcolumn!<CR>
:set cursorline
:set cursorcolumn

"colorscheme
set t_Co=256
highlight Normal guibg=black guifg=white
set background=dark
"let base16colorspace=256  " Access colors present in 256 colorspace

"syntax highlighting
:syntax on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cl setlocal ft=cpp
set hlsearch
syntax enable
set number

"speed optimizations
set nocompatible
set ttyfast
set lazyredraw

"don't auto-wrap
set tw=0

"split default right and down
set splitbelow
set splitright

"pathogen plugins
execute pathogen#infect()

"airline statusline
set laststatus=2
"let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

" enable mouse scrolling
set mouse=in
```

Comment: You can't do *anything* about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the built-in precedence; unfortunately, this cannot be changed.

My guess is that disrupting the column (especially for multiple subsequent lines) would make the setting (that should aid aligning / locating stuff) ineffective, whereas for the horizontal line, this isn't so serious, as the highlighting itself serves as an optical aid.